# Can I overload init from C++ side in pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, constructor-overloading

If in C++ a class had an overloaded constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    std::string name;
public:
    MyClass(){};
    MyClass(std::string name_){ name = name_;}
};
```

how do I expose this to python? Can I use `py::overload_cast` and `py::init` together?

Currently I expose the first one:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(ex_module, module_handle){
    module_handle.doc() = "ex class";

    py::class_<MyClass>(module_handle, "PyEx")
        .def(py::init<>())
        ;
}
```

(Note that I'm using C++20 and python >=3.10)

I want to be able to do:

```
new_obj = PyEx()
new_obj = PyEx("blah")
```

Currently, `PyEx("blah")` isn't throwing any errors, but it's also not really passing `blah` into the C++ constructor. I check this by adding a print statement in the second constructor.

**Edit:** simplified the question.

Comment: Don't think that error has anything to do with Pybind11. You defined the constructor of `Ex` to take a single argument `keyword_arg`... then in the call `Ex("blah", keyword_arg="foo")` assign it two different values -- first the positional `"blah"`, second the named `"foo"`.

Comment: @DanMašek Sure, but then how can I overload the constructor and also have keyword arguments on the python side? Ok maybe I can simplify the question.
edit: I simplified the question because I was convoluting two separate issues.

Comment: The documentation says "To define multiple overloaded constructors, simply declare one after the other using the .def(py::init<...>()) syntax." Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use any `overload_cast` tricks, because exposing the constructor is different than exposing a method where you pass the pointer to member function. You just need to define your single argument constructor after (or before) the default one:

```
    py::class_<MyClass>(module_handle, "PyEx")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def(py::init<std::string>())
        ;
```